# Using 4 KByte/sec Channel for Voice Transmission

Tags: audio, voip, audio-streaming, opus

Is it possible to transfer voice through a channel that allows not greater than 4KByte/sec speed? I am looking for the lowest quality transmission method. I considered [Opus](https://mf4.xiph.org/jenkins/view/opus/job/opus/ws/doc/html/index.html) codec but looks like the lowest rate it supports is 6 kb/s.

Please, refer me to such methods.

Comment: Both narrowband and wideband AMR would fit that criterion.

Answer (score 1):

The lowest rate supported by Opus is 6 k*bit*/s and you have 4 kByte/s, so 32 kbit/s. At 32 kbit/s you can have very high quality voice.